# How to call Partitioner in Haoop v 0.21

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

In my application I want to create as many reducer jobs as possible based on the keys. Now my current implementation writes all the keys and values in a single (reducer) output file. So to solve this, I have used one partitioner but I cannot call the class.The partitioner should be called after the selection Map task and before the selection reduce task but it did not.The code of the partitioner is the following

```
public class MultiWayJoinPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, Text> {
@Override
public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int nbPartitions) {
return (key.getFirst().hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % nbPartitions;
return 0;
}
}
```

Is this code is correct to partition the files based on the keys and values and the output will be transfer to the reducer automatically??

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show all of your code, but there is usually a class (called the "Job" or "MR" class) that configures the mapper, reducer, partitioner, etc. and then actually submits the job to hadoop.  In this class you will have a job configuration object that has many properties, one of which is the number of reducers.  Set this property to whatever number your hadoop configuration can handle.

Once the job is configured with a given number of reducers, that number will be passed into your partition (which looks correct, by the way).  Your partitioner will start returning the appropriate reducer/partition for the key/value pair. That's how you get as many reducers as possible.